# Finding LinkedIn Username from LinkedIn ID

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I have a database of LinkedIn IDs, however I need to find their LinkedIn Usernames. I would welcome if you can advise how can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

That information is not available via any LinkedIn API calls.  The member ID that you retrieve should be sufficient for all your needs.

Comment: how to get username or profile link from member id like 308407637